# Updating column total after manually changing value in child table cell R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a nested DataTable in my Shiny app. The child table allows the user to go in and manually edit the values in a few columns. The goal here is to have a `totals` row at the end of the table that sums up the column. If a user goes in and changes a value then the `totals` row will update with the new column sum. For example, If I was the user and wanted to change the `Share (%)` for `Daytime` to `20` the `Totals` row would update to `105`,

I am able to create this functionality on a regular DataTable, but I am having a hard time creating this for a nested child table.

**Child Table**

[image]

```
structure(list(Daypart = c("Daytime", "Early Fringe", "Early Morning", 
"Early News", "Late Fringe", "Late News", "Prime Access", "Prime Time"
), `Share (%)` = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 10, 10, 10, 10), `Spot:30 (%)` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Spot:15 (%)` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), `Gross CPM` = c("$0", "$0", "$0", "$0", "$0", "$0", "$0", 
"$0")), .Names = c("Daypart", "Share (%)", "Spot:30 (%)", "Spot:15 (%)", 
"Gross CPM"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Parent Table**

[image]

```
structure(list(Market = c("ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY"
), `Gross CPP` = c("$0", "$0"), `Gross CPM` = c("$0", "$0"), 
    `Historical Composite Gross CPP (if applicable)` = c("$0", 
    "$0"), `Historical Composite Gross CPM (if applicable)` = c("$0", 
    "$0")), .Names = c("Market", "Gross CPP", "Gross CPM", "Historical Composite Gross CPP (if applicable)", 
"Historical Composite Gross CPM (if applicable)"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Code**

```
# Module that renders the table
tableMod <- function(input, output, session, runButton, data){
  # this variable will be in sync with your datatable
  df <- reactiveVal(data)

  output$update_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    runButton()
    isolate(
      datatable(
        df() %>%
          bind_rows(
            summarise_all(.,
                          funs(
                            if (is.numeric(.))
                              sum(.)
                            else if (is.factor(.)) "-"
                            else "Sub Total")
            )
          ),
        selection = 'none', editable = TRUE
      )
    )
  })

  # Observe the event
  observeEvent(input$x1_cell_edit, {
    new_df <- df()
    row <- input$x1_cell_edit$row
    col <- input$x1_cell_edit$col
    value <- as.numeric(input$x1_cell_edit$value)
    new_df[row, col] <- value
    df(new_df)
  })

  list(updated_df = df)
}

# Module used to display the updated table
tableUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  dataTableOutput(ns("update_table"))
}
```

**Server**

```
 # Bind the market level and mix breakout data together for the final table
    market_mix_table <- reactive({
      markets <- market_costings_gross_net()
      mix_breakout <- daypart_break_out()

      # Need to use replicate() on mix_breakout_table for cases when there is an arbitrary number of rows in markets 
      n <-  nrow(markets)
      children_list <- replicate(n, mix_breakout, simplify = FALSE)
      # Make the dataframe
      # This must be met length(children) == nrow(dat)
      Dat <- NestedData(
        dat = markets,
        children = children_list
      )
      return(Dat)
    })
    # Render the table
    output$daypartTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      # Whether to show row names (set TRUE or FALSE)
      rowNames <- FALSE
      colIdx <- as.integer(rowNames)
      # The data
      Dat <- market_mix_table()
      # Table
      table <- DT::datatable(
        callModule(tableMod, "opfun", runButton = reactive(input$opt_run), data = Dat), 
        callback = callback_js, 
        rownames = rowNames, 
        escape = -colIdx-1,
          options = list(
            columnDefs = list(
              list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(Dat)-1+colIdx),
              list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = colIdx),
              list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all")
            )
          )
        )
      # Some faancy Java magic
      path <- getwd()
      dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
        "CellEdit", "1.0.19", path, 
        script = "dataTables.cellEdit.js", stylesheet = "dataTables.cellEdit.css")
      table$dependencies <- c(table$dependencies, list(dep))
      return(table)
    })
```

**UI**

```
# Testing out the new observeEvent handling
tableUI("opfun"),
actionButton("opt_run", "Run"),


# Display table
DT::dataTableOutput(
 width = "100%",
 "daypartTable"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with a footer and the `footerCallback` option. But it does not handle the columns with a "$".

```
df1 <- iris[1:3,]
df2 <- data.frame(
  Daypart = c("Morning", "Afternoon", "Evening"),
  X1 = c(3, 2, 4),
  X2 = c(10, 20, 30), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# function to make the required dataframe
NestedData <- function(dat, children){
  stopifnot(length(children) == nrow(dat))
  g <- function(d){
    if(is.data.frame(d)){
      purrr::transpose(d)
    }else{
      purrr::transpose(NestedData(d[[1]], children = d$children))
    }
  }
  subdats <- lapply(children, g)
  oplus <- sapply(subdats, function(x) if(length(x)) "&oplus;" else "")
  cbind(" " = oplus, dat, "_details" = I(subdats), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

# make the required dataframe
# one must have: length(children) == nrow(dat)
Dat <- NestedData(
  dat = df1, 
  children = list(df2, df2, df2)
)

## whether to show row names (set TRUE or FALSE)
rowNames <- FALSE
colIdx <- as.integer(rowNames)

## make the callback
parentRows <- which(Dat[,1] != "")
callback = JS(
  "function onUpdate(updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue) {};",
  "table.MakeCellsEditable({",
  "  onUpdate: onUpdate,",
  "  inputCss: 'my-input-class',",
  "  confirmationButton: {",
  "    confirmCss: 'my-confirm-class',",
  "    cancelCss: 'my-cancel-class'",
  "  }",
  "});",
  sprintf("var parentRows = [%s];", toString(parentRows-1)),
  sprintf("var j0 = %d;", colIdx),
  "var nrows = table.rows().count();",
  "for(var i=0; i < nrows; ++i){",
  "  if(parentRows.indexOf(i) > -1){",
  "    table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }else{",
  "    table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$().removeClass('details-control');",
  "  }",
  "}",
  "",
  "// make the table header of the nested table",
  "var format = function(d, childId){",
  "  if(d != null){",
  "    var html = ", 
  "      '<table class=\"display compact hover\" ' + ",
  "      'style=\"padding-left: 30px;\" id=\"' + childId + '\"><thead><tr>';",
  "    for(var key in d[d.length-1][0]){",
  "      html += '<th>' + key + '</th>';",
  "    }",
  "    html += '</tr></thead><tfoot><tr>'",
  "    for(var key in d[d.length-1][0]){",
  "      html += '<th></th>';",
  "    }",
  "    return html + '</tr></tfoot></table>';",
  "  } else {",
  "    return '';",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// row callback to style the rows of the child tables",
  "var rowCallback = function(row, dat, displayNum, index){",
  "  if($(row).hasClass('odd')){",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', '#E6FF99');",
  "    }, function() {",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
  "    });",
  "  } else {",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', '#DDFF75');",
  "    }, function() {",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
  "    });",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// header callback to style the header of the child tables",
  "var headerCallback = function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
  "  $('th', thead).css({",
  "    'border-top': '3px solid indigo',", 
  "    'color': 'indigo',",
  "    'background-color': '#fadadd'",
  "  });",
  "};",
  "",
  "// footer callback to display the totals",
  "var footerCallback = function(tfoot, data, start, end, display){",
  "  $('th', tfoot).css('background-color', '#fed8b1');",
  "  var api = this.api();",
  "  api.columns().eq(0).each(function(index){",
  "    if(index == 0) return $(api.column(index).footer()).html('Total');",
  "    var coldata = api.column(index).data();",
  "    var total = coldata", 
  "          .reduce(function(a, b){return parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b)}, 0);",
  "    $(api.column(index).footer()).html(total);",
  "  })",
  "}",
  "",
  "// make the datatable",
  "var format_datatable = function(d, childId){",
  "  var dataset = [];",
  "  var n = d.length - 1;",
  "  for(var i = 0; i < d[n].length; i++){",
  "    var datarow = $.map(d[n][i], function (value, index) {",
  "      return [value];",
  "    });",
  "    dataset.push(datarow);",
  "  }",
  "  var id = 'table#' + childId;",
  "  if (Object.keys(d[n][0]).indexOf('_details') === -1) {",
  "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "                 'data': dataset,",
  "                 'autoWidth': true,",
  "                 'deferRender': true,",
  "                 'info': false,",
  "                 'lengthChange': false,",
  "                 'ordering': d[n].length > 1,",
  "                 'order': [],",
  "                 'paging': false,",
  "                 'scrollX': false,",
  "                 'scrollY': false,",
  "                 'searching': false,",
  "                 'sortClasses': false,",
  "                 'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "                 'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "                 'footerCallback': footerCallback,",
  "                 'columnDefs': [{targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}]",
  "               });",
  "  } else {",
  "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "            'data': dataset,",
  "            'autoWidth': true,",
  "            'deferRender': true,",
  "            'info': false,",
  "            'lengthChange': false,",
  "            'ordering': d[n].length > 1,",
  "            'order': [],",
  "            'paging': false,",
  "            'scrollX': false,",
  "            'scrollY': false,",
  "            'searching': false,",
  "            'sortClasses': false,",
  "            'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "            'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "            'footerCallback': footerCallback,",
  "            'columnDefs': [", 
  "              {targets: -1, visible: false},", 
  "              {targets: 0, orderable: false, className: 'details-control'},", 
  "              {targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}",
  "             ]",
  "          }).column(0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }",
  "  subtable.MakeCellsEditable({",
  "    onUpdate: onUpdate,",
  "    inputCss: 'my-input-class',",
  "    confirmationButton: {",
  "      confirmCss: 'my-confirm-class',",
  "      cancelCss: 'my-cancel-class'",
  "    }",
  "  });",
  "};",
  "",
  "// display the child table on click",
  "table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function(){",
  "  var tbl = $(this).closest('table'),",
  "      tblId = tbl.attr('id'),",
  "      td = $(this),",
  "      row = $(tbl).DataTable().row(td.closest('tr')),",
  "      rowIdx = row.index();",
  "  if(row.child.isShown()){",
  "    row.child.hide();",
  "    td.html('&oplus;');",
  "  } else {",
  "    var childId = tblId + '-child-' + rowIdx;",
  "    row.child(format(row.data(), childId)).show();",
  "    td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
  "    format_datatable(row.data(), childId);",
  "  }",
  "});")

## the datatable
dtable <- datatable(
  Dat, callback = callback, rownames = rowNames, escape = -colIdx-1,
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(
      list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(Dat)-1+colIdx),
      list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = colIdx),
      list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all")
    )
  )
)
path <- "~/Work/R/DT" # folder containing the files dataTables.cellEdit.js
                      # and dataTables.cellEdit.css
dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "CellEdit", "1.0.19", path, 
  script = "dataTables.cellEdit.js", stylesheet = "dataTables.cellEdit.css")
dtable$dependencies <- c(dtable$dependencies, list(dep))
dtable
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for another great solution. I am going to assume that if I need anymore table functionality that it will need to be on the `callback` side of things? Like if I wanted to have the parent `Gross CPM` to update as the child `Gross CPM` updates?

Comment: if I wanted to have the `parent` `Gross CPM` to update as the `child` `Gross CPM` updates would I need to add that into the `callback` section